# После запуска `ng test` в открывшемся окне пропадает отчет о выполнении тестов

Tags: angular2, jasmine, karma, angular-cli

Когда я выполняю ng test то после выполнения тестов я вижу только это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя в консоли показывается что все тесты выполнились

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окошко Jasmine появляется на момент выполнения тестов и потом исчезает.
Как мне увидеть результат тестов в браузере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в конфиге надо добавить

```
client: {
  clearContext: false
},
```